# DNXCore ARM Releases on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: asp.net-core, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

I'm trying to get my dnxcore rc1 final app installed on my Raspberry Pi 2, how can I do this?  I don't even know what ARM releases are available, is there a human readable list somewhere that I can refer to?

I assume I have to get the ARM release onto my dev system and then publish for that before x-copying over to the Pi?

The tutorials I've followed so far have not worked and refer to beta7, I can't rollback months of work to test it on that unfortunately.

Nick.

Comment: Have you tried installing the latest arm runtime with `dnvm install latest -arch arm -r coreclr`

Comment: Just tried that, but says "There are no runtimes matching the name dnx-coreclr-win-arm on feed https://www.nuget.org/api/v2.". So I added the unstable build feed https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetmaster/api/v2/.  Then tried again, got the same problem, so then tried "dnvm install latest -unstable -arch arm -r coreclr", and got the error "Unable to find any runtime packages on the feed!".  It stated it was using the unstable feed.

Comment: You can install it like this (from Powershell, in cmd use `SET` to set the environment variable):
`$env:DNX_FEED="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetmaster/api/v2"` and then `dnvm install latest -r CoreClr -arch arm`. You probably will want to reset the DNX_FEED env variable afterwards...

Comment: Excellent thanks that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install the ARM runtime you first need to set the right feed (this is how you do this in Powershell, in cmd use SET to set the environment variable):

```
$env:DNX_FEED="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetmaster/api/v2" 
dnvm install latest -r CoreClr -arch arm
```

You probably will want to reset the DNX_FEED env variable afterwards..